# How do I find "Autoscroll from/to Source" in PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

The Auto-scroll to/from Source features used to appear in the PyCharm Project View, but I don't see the, nor is there anything in the Find Action autocomplete.

How do I enable these?

[image: menu with missing autoscroll]

Comment: AFAIK it's called `Always Select Opened File` now (Autoscroll **from** Source). Another one (Autoscroll **to** Source) is `Open Files with Single Click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actions have been renamed improve an user experience for those who move from other IDEs: **Autoscroll to Source** -> **Open Files with Single Click**, **Autoscroll from Source** -> **Always Select Opened FIle**; see [IDEA-217044](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217044)